# Searching for a word in a file & then printing the value next to it in Tcl

Tags: regex, file, tcl

I have the following text file with me:

```
 ..............................................
 ..............................................
 ..............................................
 ..............................................
 xyz (MTU)                             301.2017
```

I tried the following :

```
set fd [open "textfile.file" r]
set data [read $fd]
set input_list [split $data "\n"]
set pattern [lsearch -all -inline $data "xyz (MTU)*"]
foreach elem $pattern{
    puts "[lindex $elem 3]"
}
```

But it gives a blank output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there's a space at the start of the line. If I add a space at the start of the pattern, it works:

```
% set pattern [lsearch -all -inline -glob $input_list " xyz (MTU)*"]
{ xyz (MTU)                             301.2017}
```

Comment: Didn't work: I also tried                                                                             
set pattern [lsearch -all -inline -glob $input_list "\s+xyz (MTU)*"]

Comment: The problem with glob patterns is that they are inclined to be hypersensitive to little things. Also, you were putting the wrong thing into the `lsearch` but I thought that was just a typo. In general, it can help to prefilter the stuff you are searching over with `lmap` (requires Tcl 8.6) or to convert into a form other than a simple list. It's a big topic, really...